# Using html5 manifest to store images and javascript locally on iPad to reduce bandwidth and improve page load times?

Tags: performance, ipad, html, manifest, offline

I am currently developing an online iPad version of my open source eCommerce platform to be used by salesreps at Trade Shows.  The app does not need to be fully offline as they will need access to the live data on the webserver.

The reps will have limited connectivity (mainly through teathered iPhones or limited WiFi) so I want to minimise the amount of data loaded remotely.

I am investigating using html5 manifest and was wondering if anyone could enlighten me?

1. Can I effectively prime the iPad with all the images used in the site along with the css and javascript files?  Thus preventing the browser requesting them from the online server?
2. If so, how do I do it?  I was hoping not to have to make a list of every file in the manifest file.  (seems a very long winded way to do this!)  Would opening a browser page on the iPad with every image displayed on it work?  (This could be done where high speed broadband is available)
3. Does anyone have a link to an "idiots guide" style article on how to set this up?

Any ideas, tips or pointers would be welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found this which provides most of the answers ... http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/chapOfflineApplicationCache.html#ch06_id35815732

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found these sites most useful when starting to develop offline web applications:

- http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html
- http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/appcache/beginner/
- http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/how-to-create-offline-webapps-on-the-iphone

You can prevent your browser from re-downloading all the css, images, and javascript by listing them in the CACHE section of the manifest. You will need to list all the files that you want to be cached.

You should also list the urls that you do not want to be cached in the NETWORK section